# Como ver descripcion/documentacion de los metodos de java en Vs Strudio code?

Tags: java, vscode

Empecé a usar Visual Studio Code, y quiero que al pasar el cursor por un método o en el menu que aparece cuando se aprieta ctrl+ esp, me aparezca la descripción del mismo, como se hace en todos los IDES, por si no se entendió lo que quiero es esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por alguna razón, me aparece solo la documentación de las clases, pero no la de los métodos. Por cierto estoy usando la extensión de RedHat para usar java en vs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que el error se daba porque estaba agregando a Visual Studio Code, proyectos que había creado en otro IDE, supongo que había un conflictos debido a la forma en la que manejan el proyecto los distintos IDES.

SOLUCION: Lo que hice fue crear un proyecto nuevo en Visual Studio Code y pasar las clases de mi proyecto en el otro IDE, a la carpeta de este proyecto nuevo. También tienes que tener la extensión InteliSense para que funcione.

Comment: Estaría bien que indagues un poco más para descubrir la verdadera razón y que la respuesta quede más completa.